# Implement Fingerprint Login To .NET MVC WebApp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

How can I implement a fingerprint login to my .NET MVC Web Application?

**I want to:**

1. Click a button in my MVC web application.
2. The button will open some application in my cell phone that will allow me to
   insert my fingerprint.
3. Then the result (success or failure) will be returned back to my web app.

Is it possible?

All I've found is solutions that use the fingerprint device that is connected to the computer, or mobile apps that connect to the cell-phone fingerprint app.
I want to connect my **web application** to **some mobile app** and do the fingerprint authentication via that mobile app.

Comment: [Microsoft Account external login setup with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @LeiYang I don't see any help with this link can you provide example?

Comment: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API)

Answer (score 0):

You need a client app for your phone to perform biometric, then api client on computer to receive login validation.

What type of phone?

You need to create an api or at min a socket/port client/server to recieve and send your packets between pc and phone. So two applications.

Comment: tanks, do you know some secure mobile app, that perform biometric, so I can use it to send the login validation to my api ?

Comment: @Felix why my question is vague? and yes I think that this kind of operation exist already therefor I am looking for some step by step  (I didn't downvoted)

Comment: is "a button in your MVC application" in the browser? or in a native mobile application? what is the infrastructure on your phone to accept fingerprints and how is it tied to your application? what returns result to where? Obviously, there are a number of applications (most banking apps, for example) that allow users to sign in with a fingerprint. But those are native mobile apps; nothing to do with HTML or MVC. That's why SO requires that you put your code as part of the question

Comment: @Felix The question is about a way to solve the problem, therefor their is no code.
the button is of course in the html, it's a web app, the user can only click in html.
the solution needs to work on all phones. the mobile app should return the result to the mvc web application or as RichardReed advised to a API